# Filter out array of objects on same key being empty ("")

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have an array of objects that needs to be filtered. It looks something like this:

```
        let array = [
            {
                "id": "",
                "first_name": "Kary",
                "last_name": "Thorndale",
                "email": "kthorndale1@nifty.com",
                "gender": "Female",
                "ip_address": "172.152.36.109"
            },
            {
                "id": "",
                "first_name": "Westley",
                "last_name": "Emmott",
                "email": "wemmott2@cisco.com",
                "gender": "Male",
                "ip_address": "104.62.125.170"
            },
            {
                "id": "",
                "first_name": "Gavrielle",
                "last_name": "Danihel",
                "email": "gdanihel3@yandex.ru",
                "gender": "Female",
                "ip_address": "98.98.209.17"
            }
    ];
```

I have only one condition - if key in all objects is empty remove it from all objects.

I can use jQuery or loDash if it is faster or there is any need for it.

There shouldn't be more than 15-20 objects in array and there will be up to 15 arrays like this that needs to go through filter.

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  You'll find this is an open and sharing community; however not one that simply does the work for others.  Please first make an attempt at solving the question and show where you are stuck.

Comment: Where did you got stuck?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please show us what you tried so that people can help you

Comment: There is no “key”.  Are you talking about the id field being empty?

Comment: what is it? the id, the object, the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could count the empty values for the same key and map new objects without all emty properties.

```js
var array = [{ id: "", first_name: "Kary", last_name: "Thorndale", email: "kthorndale1@nifty.com", gender: "Female", ip_address: "172.152.36.109" }, { id: "", first_name: "Westley", last_name: "Emmott", email: "wemmott2@cisco.com", gender: "Male", ip_address: "104.62.125.170" }, { id: "", first_name: "Gavrielle", last_name: "Danihel", email: "gdanihel3@yandex.ru", gender: "Female", ip_address: "98.98.209.17" }],
    keys = Array
        .from(array.reduce((m, o) => {
            Object.entries(o).forEach(([k, v]) => m.set(k, (m.get(k) || 0) + +!!v));
            return m;
        }, new Map))
        .filter(({ 1: v }) => v)
        .map(([k]) => k),
    result = array.map(o => Object.assign(...keys.map(k => ({ [k]: o[k] }))));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

A slightly better version with a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

```js
var array = [{ id: "", first_name: "Kary", last_name: "Thorndale", email: "kthorndale1@nifty.com", gender: "Female", ip_address: "172.152.36.109" }, { id: "", first_name: "Westley", last_name: "Emmott", email: "wemmott2@cisco.com", gender: "Male", ip_address: "104.62.125.170" }, { id: "", first_name: "Gavrielle", last_name: "Danihel", email: "gdanihel3@yandex.ru", gender: "Female", ip_address: "98.98.209.17" }],
    keys = Array.from(
        array.reduce(
            (s, o) => Object.entries(o).reduce((t, [k, v]) => v ? t.add(k) : t, s),
            new Set
        )
    ),
    result = array.map(o => Object.assign(...keys.map(k => ({ [k]: o[k] }))));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Tnx for help, i had similar solution but it was depending on loDash too much. I will use your's as better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `findIndex` to get check if there exist empty string as a value for that specific key. If it is `-1` then that key have no empty string as value.

If it is not greater than `-1` then you can use `map` to return a new array and inside the callback function create a new object and set the key and it's value

```js
let array = [{
    "id": "",
    "first_name": "Kary",
    "last_name": "Thorndale",
    "email": "kthorndale1@nifty.com",
    "gender": "Female",
    "ip_address": "172.152.36.109"
  },
  {
    "id": "",
    "first_name": "Westley",
    "last_name": "Emmott",
    "email": "wemmott2@cisco.com",
    "gender": "Male",
    "ip_address": "104.62.125.170"
  },
  {
    "id": "",
    "first_name": "Gavrielle",
    "last_name": "Danihel",
    "email": "gdanihel3@yandex.ru",
    "gender": "Female",
    "ip_address": "98.98.209.17"
  }
];

let getIndex = array.findIndex(function(item) {
  return item.id === '';

})
let newArray = [];
if (getIndex !== -1) {
  newArray = array.map(function(item) {
    return Object.assign({}, {
      "first_name": item['first_name'],
      "last_name": item['last_name'],
      "email": item['email'],
      "gender": item['gender'],
      "ip_address": item['ip_address'],
      "item.gender": item['item.gender']
    })
  })
}

console.log(newArray)
```

Alternatively you can use array `some` & `reduce`

```js
let array = [{
    "id": "",
    "first_name": "Kary",
    "last_name": "Thorndale",
    "email": "kthorndale1@nifty.com",
    "gender": "Female",
    "ip_address": "172.152.36.109"
  },
  {
    "id": "",
    "first_name": "Westley",
    "last_name": "Emmott",
    "email": "wemmott2@cisco.com",
    "gender": "Male",
    "ip_address": "104.62.125.170"
  },
  {
    "id": "",
    "first_name": "Gavrielle",
    "last_name": "Danihel",
    "email": "gdanihel3@yandex.ru",
    "gender": "Female",
    "ip_address": "98.98.209.17"
  }
];

let __e = array.some((item) => {
  return item.id === '';
})
if (__e) {
  let z = array.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
    let k = Object.assign({}, curr);
    delete k['id'];
    acc.push(k);
    return acc

  }, [])
  console.log(z)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is concise solution with lodash.

```js
let data = [ { "id": "", "first_name": "Kary", "last_name": "Thorndale", "email": "kthorndale1@nifty.com", "gender": "Female", "ip_address": "172.152.36.109" }, { "id": "", "first_name": "Westley", "last_name": "Emmott", "email": "wemmott2@cisco.com", "gender": "Male", "ip_address": "104.62.125.170" }, { "id": "", "first_name": "Gavrielle", "last_name": "Danihel", "email": "gdanihel3@yandex.ru", "gender": "Female", "ip_address": "98.98.209.17" } ];

const mrg = (r,c) => _.mergeWith(r,c, (o,s) => _.isEmpty(o) ? s : o)

const result = _.map(data, x => 
  _.omit(x,_.chain(data).reduce(mrg).pickBy(_.isEmpty).keys().value()))

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Main idea here is to merge all objects to one since that way we would know right away which key is empty everywhere. We do this with the `mrg` function which inside uses [**mergeWith**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#mergeWith) to provide a `customizer`. Main purpose of that function is to make sure we merge on a non empty value.